# TClientDataSet.XMLData leaking memory

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I´ve done a simple php script that returns a exactly xml datapacket from a mysql server over the web, based on the ClientDataset.CommandText property.

```
procedure TMainDataModule.AbertasAfterOpen(Dataset: TDataset);
begin
  DataSet.Tag := 0;
end;

procedure TMainDataModule.AbertasBeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if Dataset.Tag = 0 then
  begin
    DataSet.Tag := 1;
    with DataSet as TClientDataSet do
      XMLData := myWebService.XMLDataPacket(CommandText);
  end;
end;
```

MyWebService is a simple class to post the CommandText to the php script, decode/encode64 the xml and return the data.

It works ok, but madExcept/FastMM reports memory leaks in ClientDataset.SetXmlData.

I cant see why, any ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is it reporting exactly?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A3b0DxM9

Answer (score 0):

in Delphi XE, the WebService had a memory leak which should be solved in DXE2. Which version are you using? Maybe it's not the ClientDataSet, but the WebService in your case too?

QC#105538

Comment: My WS is custom made with indy components, and i´m using BDS2006. If you check the paste.bin you will verify it occurs inside clientdataset. Thanks for your time.